# Microsoft.Data.Edm reference error

Tags: .net, nopcommerce

I have Nopcommerce(NOP.Web) application. When I build this application, there is 
`Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll` inside BIN folder with version 5.7.0.62414.

But when I rebuild my plugin, which is copied into Nop.Web application, the version of this dll is changed to 5.6.4.62175. and I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Edm' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

So, I guess there is some reference different inside my plugin and Nop.Web

How can I know which one and what should I do?

I have found out that there is this reference inside "Nop.Web.Framework.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache" file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.6.4\bin.NETFramework\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll

I can't find from where this reference came from. It is also reference to correct dll(5.7.X.X) inside the same file:

> d:\MyProjects\Libraries\Nop.Services\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll

And in app.config i have this:

> bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />

But when build it always take 5.6.4.X version of dll.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the project reference to `Microsoft.Data.Edm` assembly. Check Path and Version for your referenced assembly. As an example, I have included how it looks like for a random reference in one of my projects:

[image: reference properties example]